# Check whether a user is authenticated inside an ExceptionController

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I have a custom ExceptionController to throw custom error pages and it works correctly, it shows my custom pages according to the http error code, the thing that brought me here is that if you are not authenticated in the system and tries to accesss to a kind of protected route, it throws an 404 instead of an 401.

I did said that is a kind of protected route because of this:

```
#security.yaml

access_control:
    - { path: ^\/admin, roles: ROLE_ATA_ALL }
```

I want every route behind "/admin" to be protected and be requiried to has "ROLE_ATA_ALL" to access to it.

There's an example:

say that I go to "/admin/NoRegisteredRoute", while I'm actually authenticated, what I do expect is to show my 404 page but if you try to access the same route without being autheticated then it should show a 401 page but it always always shows the 404 page no matter what. The `access_control` was not working correctly so I decided to try to check if the user is authenticated directly in my controller so I did this:

```
public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, ParameterBagInterface $params, 
DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null) {
        $this->params = $params;
        $hasRole = $this->security->denyUnlessHasRole("ATA", "ALL"); // This function returns whether the current user has the ATA_ALL role

        // ...
    }
```

Having that code, when I try to access to an unregistered route I get none of my custom pages error but a symfony one that says:

> The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

But isn't the `{ path: ^\/admin, roles: ROLE_ATA_ALL }` that configured firewall the error asks for?

This is behaving kinda weird because if I do the authentication process, then head to a unregistered route, my debugging toolbar says theres no authenticated user but when I go to a registered one, I actually shows the authenticated user as it should.

I only want to know if a user is authenticated inside my showAction function so I could throw a 401 when its necessary

Answer (score 1):

Symfony will try and find the route first so if its not found then it will throw a 404 exception. If it exists then it will do the necessary authentication and show the 401 if the user is not authenticated.

You could set up a catchall route as /admin/{params} in one of your controllers. Just make sure you add it to the end of your routes.